# GitHub actions: connect to AWS to run .sh file

Tags: github-actions

I want to automate the CI process where the tool I use is connected to the GitHub and there are 2 dbs After a developer pushes to one db, the second db should have the capability to pull the resources that were pushed in the first db. The tool (hosted on aws) provides a .sh file which triggers the pull for the second db. How can I connect to the aws instance from GitHub using actions and point to the aws folder and make use of the .sh file to trigger the pull.

I am new to Github and could not find suitable solution to resolve my issue.
Looking for any help/advice. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be to use the [`unfor19/install-aws-cli-action`](https://github.com/unfor19/install-aws-cli-action), to benefit from aws CLI.

You can see an example in "[The CI / CD pipeline of Github Action for serverless lambda function containerization deployment.](https://medium.com/thelorry-product-tech-data/the-ci-cd-pipeline-of-github-action-for-serverless-lambda-function-containerization-deployment-a79ef339b363)" from [Dr. Tri Basuki Kurniawan](https://github.com/tribasuki74).

```yaml
steps:      
      - name: Install AWS CLI        
        uses: unfor19/install-aws-cli-action@v1        
        with:          
          version: 1        
        env:          
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}          
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{                              ->            
            secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}          
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}             - name: Configure AWS credentials        
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1        
        with:          
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}                
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{                              ->        
            secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}          
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}             - name: Login to Amazon ECR        
        id: login-ecr        
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1                  - name: Check out code        
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
...
```

But depending on the nature of your database, you also have more specialized actions like "[Labs: Cross-Region Replication for RDS](https://github.com/kploesser/aws-cross-region-rds)".